# Add custom column to SQL table in Qlik

Tags: sql, qlikview, qliksense

I uploaded into Qlik my sql code and i want to do calculations in Qlik and add a column of these custom calculations. How can i do this? My code:

```
SQLAS:
SQL

select 
costs.FLI, costs.COMPANY_NAME, costs.QTY_REC,    
fleet.COUNT_OF_TAILS_NO,
pricel.NE_pricel, 
 pn.atas        

from                      
(select *
from FLI_1

union all

select *
from FLI_2
) costs

 left join fleet on (costs.fli=fltc.fleet .fli)

left join (select * from price
           ) pricel on costs.fli=pricel.fli
 left join (select * from  atata) atas on costs.fli=atas.fli

 ;

 LOAD SQLAS,

   If([FLI] = 'FLI110', 69,0 ) as [NAUJAS]
   resident SQLAS;
```

However , i get an error:
[image]

If i remove `resident SQLAS;` i see that there are no mistakes, however, i cannot find the new created column.

How should i properly add column to an Qlik SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LOAD 
  SQLAS,
  If([FLI] = 'FLI110', 69,0 ) as [NAUJAS]
Resident 
  SQLAS;
```

This statement is translated to: load from `SQLAS` table 2 fields: `SQLAS` and `FLI` (with some transformations on it).

Based on your sql the table `SQLAS` dont have field `SQLAS`. If you want to load all fields use `*`. Then the resident load will look like:

```
SQLAS1:
LOAD 
  *,
  If([FLI] = 'FLI110', 69,0 ) as [NAUJAS]
Resident 
  SQLAS;
```

After this load you'll need to drop the original `SQLAS` table, otherwise you'll end up with massive [Synthetic Table](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.0/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/synthetic-keys.htm)

`Drop Table SQLAS;`

Another aproach is to use [Preceding LOAD](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/preceding-load.htm) to avoid `resident load` and `syntetic keys`

```
SQLAS:
Load
  *,
  If([FLI] = 'FLI110', 69,0 ) as [NAUJAS]
;
SQLAS:
SQL
select 
  costs.FLI, costs.COMPANY_NAME, costs.QTY_REC,  
  ... the rest of the original sql
;
```

The script above will produce the same result table but without the need to load everything in new table.